# Nginx: can use regex $ capture in access_log but not error_log

Tags: nginx

I have the following Nginx configuration using regular expression server names, so I can easily add static sites without adding new configuration entries:

```
server {
        server_name ~^(?<domain>.+)$;
        root /home/static/sites/$domain;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/$domain-static-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/$domain-static-error.log;
}
```

This works fine for serving the site, and the access logs end up at e.g. `/var/log/nginx/example.com-static-access.log` as desired. But the error logs end up at `/var/log/nginx/$domain-static-error.log`. It does not interpolate the value of that regex capture.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure but [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/644892/nginx-set-variable-in-location) may help you

Comment: @EduardoEscobar Thank you! It claims that "error_log won't work with variables at all" so that would explain it…

Comment: @EduardoEscobar If you add that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some nginx configuration directives support variables. Whether or not variables are supported by a particular configuration directive in a particular parameter is explicitly documented.   E.g., the `access_log` directive [description](http://nginx.org/r/access_log) say:

> The file path can contain variables (0.7.6+), but such logs have some constraints...

The `error_log` directive does not support variables at all, and accordingly its [description](http://nginx.org/r/error_log) doesn't say anything about variables support. Note that this is intentional: error logs are to log errors, including low-level ones like memory allocation errors, and error logging is designed to avoid operations which can fail.

In other words, `error_log` does not support variables and there are no plans to add such a support. Use some fixed name instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well then, take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/644892/nginx-set-variable-in-location). Indeed, it seems to be that `error_log` path won't accept variables in nginx configuration file.

Comment: I accepted the later answer because it was more fleshed out – hope that's alright. Thank you so much again for helping me solve this!